# $this->validate causes "Failed to load response data"

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have the following external form:

```
  <form method="POST" action="http://infused.local/leads/post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>first_name</label>
      <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>last_name</label>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>postal_code</label>
      <input type="text" name="postal_code" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Which points to the following controller method:

```
public function post()
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
    ]);

    echo 'hello';
}
```

Via this route:

```
Route::post('leads/post', 'LeadController@post');
```

I've disabled `CSRF` protection for the form route.

- When I submit the form, I get **"Failed to load response data"** from
  Chrome.
- When I remove the `$this->validate` call, I get **"hello"**.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Why have you disabled the CSRF check?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return JSON and you can use the [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses#json-responses):

```
response()->json([
    'message' => 'hello'
]);
```

Then in your JS:

```
console.log(response.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK apparently the `validate` method just redirects you back to the previous page if there are errors, unless the response is expected to be JSON. Ended up using the Validator facade instead.

Edit: Thanks for the downvotes. This website is cancer.